# Literature and web sources for Computer Aided Geometric Design (CAGD)

Tags: geometry, reference-request, numerical-methods, computer-science

Through the Numerical Analysis lecture I came across Bèzier curves, B-Splines and Spline Interpolation and found it very interesting. The title of the chapter was Computer Aided Geometric Design and I was trying to find literature on this subject.

However, I just found one book with good reviews (Curves and Surfaces for CAGD: A Practical Guide) and it's quite expensive. I was wondering if any of you know some more book and web sources on that subject?

I'm searching for a formal approach with theorems and proofs. A lot of books you find online are not written for math students and are not formal at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many books on splines and CAGD.

Try [The Essentials of CAGD](http://www.farinhansford.com/books/essentials-cagd/) by  Farin and Hansford. All books by Farin are nice, including the one you've mentioned, [Curves and Surfaces for CAGD: A Practical Guide](http://www.farinhansford.com/books/cagd/).

There is also *Fundamentals of Computer Aided Geometric Design* by Hoschek and 
Lasser.

And the freely available [Computer Aided Geometric Design](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/cagd.pdf) by Sederberg, used in a [course](https://syllabus.byu.edu/view/SnfjQFxAdIyY.html#scheduleContainer).

Answer (score 2):

A few other on-line sources that might be useful:

[Notes by Shene](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/).

[Book by Patrikalakis and Maekawa.](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/)

[Notes by Ken Joy.](http://graphics.cs.ucdavis.edu/~joy/GeometricModelingLectures/)

But none of these use the theorem-proof style of exposition that you're seeking. For that, you might try [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E29HI2S) by Carl de Boor, thought it's really about splines, rather than CAGD.